# How to click special webelements using the new iOS UI testing?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I am testing an iOS app that uses webviews but has a native sidebar. I am able to click on the native parts, but am having trouble with some of the webview parts.

Specifically, there is a hamburger type icon. The UI recording records this:

```
XCUIApplication().buttons["\Ue15e"].tap()
```

This code doesnt compile - invalid escape sequance. I was hoping someone may know how to deal with this. Is there an iOS equivalent to androids uiautomatorviewer that could help with this? I have been reading about Appium Inspector but it gets you xpath which cant be used in iOS UI testing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to this problem.

Solution 1 is to add accessibilityIdentification to your button, so that you can call "buttons["hamburger_button"].tap() instead of having to call it by its label, which is the hamburger icon.

Solution 2, which is the "easier" solution, is to read up on String encoding of Unicode scalars: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293

At a guess, if you create a variable with the Unicode code point in question, even though it's not an "official" code point, it'll work to invoke it in the XCUI .tap() command.

Comment: Great thanks so much! Solution 2 worked for me. I will look into solution 1 as well, but I dont think it works because this was a webview - I cant find it in the storyboard.

Comment: You can define accessibilityIdentifiers in code (e.g., in whatever view controller has context on the webview:  `hamburgerButton.accessibilityIdentifier = @"hamburger_button"`

Obviously hamburgerButton is a placeholder for the particular object. ;)

Comment: @AaronSofaer I'm working on a similar problem, and I don't think that'll work because the button is defined in HTML rather than it being a native button.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Yeah, it gets... inelegant at that point, you have to have some sort of translation layer and pass the identifier as some sort of metadata... thank you for the correction!